# Broadcast a single cell value to a column

Tags: python-polars

In `pandas` it is possible to broadcast a single value to an entire column or even a slice:

```py
frame.loc[start_index:stop_index, 'a'] = frame.loc[some_row_index, 'a']
```

that is, a single value being broadcast to a `Series`.

I tried something similar with `polars` by doing

```py
frame = frame.with_column(
    pl.when(
        pl.col("Time").is_between(datetime(2022, 4, 21), datetime(2022, 4, 23))
    )
    .then(
        pl.lit(
            frame.filter(pl.col("Time") == datetime(2022, 4, 20)).select(
                "col"
            )
        )
    )
    .otherwise(pl.col("col"))
    .alias("col")
)
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert value 'shape: (1, 1)\n┌────────┐\n│ col │\n│ ---    │\n│ i64    │\n╞════════╡\n│ 14     │\n└────────┘' as a Literal
```

If i just use an integer like `pl.lit(6)` in the assignment it works fine though. How can i broadcast a single cell value to a column or a slice of a column?

---

**Edit:** Ok, so apparently indexing into the shape(1,1) DataFrame like so

```
frame.filter(pl.col("Time") == datetime(2022, 4, 20)).select("col")[0,0]
```

and casting the result to a literal asf. works but given that the documentation is rather verbose about not using square bracket notation, is there perhaps a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right to avoid square bracket notation.  A better way to do this would be to extract the single value you want as a Series.  Polars will broadcast the single value in a `when/then/otherwise`.

For instance, let's start with this data:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Time": pl.date_range(datetime(2022, 4, 18), datetime(2022, 4, 25), "1d"),
        'value': pl.arange(0, 8, eager=True),
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (8, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ Time                ┆ value │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2022-04-18 00:00:00 ┆ 0     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-19 00:00:00 ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-20 00:00:00 ┆ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-21 00:00:00 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-22 00:00:00 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-23 00:00:00 ┆ 5     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-24 00:00:00 ┆ 6     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-25 00:00:00 ┆ 7     │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

After filtering, I'll extract the value as a series, using the [`get_column`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.get_column.html) method.

```py
s = df.filter(pl.col("Time") == datetime(2022, 4, 20)).get_column('value')
s
```

```
shape: (1,)
Series: 'value' [i64]
[
        2
]
```

Notice above that this approach preserves the datatype of your column (i64).  By contrast, using square bracket notation will convert the Polars value to a Python object, which Polars must then map back to a Polars datatype in the `when/then/otherwise`.  (This sometimes leads to problems.)

In the `when/then/otherwise`, Polars will broadcast the single value in s:

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col("Time").is_between(
            datetime(2022, 4, 22),
            datetime(2022, 4, 24),
            include_bounds=True))
        .then(s)
        .otherwise(pl.col("value"))
        .alias("result")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ Time                ┆ value ┆ result │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64    │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 2022-04-18 00:00:00 ┆ 0     ┆ 0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-19 00:00:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 1      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-20 00:00:00 ┆ 2     ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-21 00:00:00 ┆ 3     ┆ 3      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-22 00:00:00 ┆ 4     ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-23 00:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-24 00:00:00 ┆ 6     ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-04-25 00:00:00 ┆ 7     ┆ 7      │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Excellent, `get_column` is exactly what i was missing.